# How to I create a custom ggplot2 smoothing stat (not just a custom lm or glm model)

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I have a function which calculates the median and 90% CI using a moving window. So for each `x = seq(xmin, xmax, by = wStep)`, I return the median and 5% and 95% quantiles for all `y` whose `x` values are less that `wSize/2` away. I want to display this as a line and ribbon using ggplot2 by creating a custom smoothing function, `stat_movingwindow()`. I can create the result I want using `geom_smooth(data = ..., stat = "identity")`:

```
moveWin <- function(d, wSize = 0.5, wStep = 0.1, 
  f = function(x) quantile(x, prob = c(0.05,0.50,0.95), na.rm = TRUE)
){
  x <- seq(min(d$x), max(d$x), by = wStep)
  y <- matrix(NA, ncol = 3, nrow = length(x))
  for(i in seq_along(x)){
    y[i, ] <- f(d[abs(d$x - x[i]) < wSize/2, ]$y)
  }
  y <- as.tibble(y)
  colnames(y) <- c("ymin","y","ymax")
  y$x <- x
  return(as.tibble(y))
}

set.seed(123)
d <- tibble(
 x= sqrt(seq(0,1,length.out = 50))*10,
 y= rnorm(50)
)

ggplot(data = d) + aes(x = x, y = y) +
  geom_smooth(
    data    = function(d) moveWin(d, wSize = 1, wStep = 0.1), 
    mapping = aes(ymin = ymin, ymax= ymax),
    stat    = "identity") + 
  geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10)
```

[image: ggplot with moving window smoothing]

Following the Vignette [Extending ggplot2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html), this is the code I've come up with so far. However, the problem is that this does not show the ribbon. Maybe I need some way to declare that this custom stat is providing the aesthetics **ymin** and **ymax**. How do I get the following code to output the similar result as above?

```
StatMovingWindow <- ggproto("StatMovingWindow", Stat,
  compute_group = function(data, scales, wSize, wStep, fun) {
    moveWin(data, wSize = wSize, wStep = wStep, f = fun)
  },

  required_aes = c("x", "y")
)
stat_movingwindow <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, 
  fun = function(d) quantile(d, probs = c(0.05, 0.50, 0.95), na.rm = TRUE),
  wStep = 0.1, wSize = 1,
  geom = "smooth", position = "identity", show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE,
  ...
){
  layer(
    stat = StatMovingWindow, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(wStep = wStep, wSize = wSize, fun = fun, ...)
  )
}

ggplot(data = d) + aes(x = x, y = y) +
  stat_movingwindow(wStep = 0.1, wSize = 1) + 
  geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10)
```

[image: custom smoothing stat does not show a ribbon]

Comment: Try adding `se = TRUE` inside `stat_movingwindow()`?

Comment: @Z.Lin this works O.o ... but I don't understand why. Why is the GeomSmooth finding this parameter? For example if I add a parameter `se=FALSE` to the definition of the `moveWin` function, it is not set to true if I call `stat_movingwindow(..., se = TRUE)`. Why does it get then for example the value of `wStep`? Both parameters are listed in the `layer(... params= ...)` call?

Comment: Pls see long(-winded) explanation below. I don't think I can explain this within the limits of the comment section...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code for `stat_movingwindow`, the line for the corresponding geom is `geom = "smooth"`:

```
stat_movingwindow <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, 
  fun = function(d) quantile(d, probs = c(0.05, 0.50, 0.95), na.rm = TRUE),
  wStep = 0.1, wSize = 1,
  geom = "smooth", # <- look here
  position = "identity", show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE,
  ...
){
  layer(
    stat = StatMovingWindow, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(wStep = wStep, wSize = wSize, fun = fun, ...)
  )
}
```

Checking the code for `geom_smooth`, we see that it includes the parameter `se = TRUE`, and uses `GeomSmooth` as its geom:

```
> geom_smooth
function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "smooth", position = "identity", 
    ..., method = "auto", formula = y ~ x, se = TRUE, # <- look here
    na.rm = FALSE, 
    show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) 
{
    params <- list(na.rm = na.rm, se = se, ...)
    if (identical(stat, "smooth")) {
        params$method <- method
        params$formula <- formula
    }
    layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomSmooth, # <- and here
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = params)
}
```

Digging deeper into GeomSmooth, we see that its `draw_group` function (which is responsible for plotting the smoothed line) has `se = FALSE` as its default parameter.

From the code, if `se == FALSE`, `has_ribbon` would be `FALSE` as well even though both `ymax` & `ymin` exists in your data you thanks to the `StatMovingWindow$compute_group` function. And this in turn means the only the result of `GeomLine$draw_panel(path, panel_params, coord)` would be returned alone, without `GeomRibbon$draw_group(ribbon, panel_params, coord)`.

```
> GeomSmooth$draw_group
<ggproto method>
  <Wrapper function>
    function (...) 
f(...)

  <Inner function (f)>
    function (data, panel_params, coord, se = FALSE) # <- look here
{
    ribbon <- transform(data, colour = NA)
    path <- transform(data, alpha = NA)
    has_ribbon <- se && !is.null(data$ymax) && !is.null(data$ymin) # <- and here
    gList(if (has_ribbon) GeomRibbon$draw_group(ribbon, panel_params, coord), 
          GeomLine$draw_panel(path, panel_params, coord))
}
```

In short, `geom_smooth`'s default parameter of `se = TRUE` overrides the default behaviour in `GeomSmooth$draw_group`, (the same holds for `stat_smooth` too) and we should do the same in `stat_movingwindow` if we want to achieve the same result.

If you expect you'll usually want the ribbon to be plotted, you can include `se = TRUE` as a parameter in your definition for `stat_movingwindow`. If it's going to be on an ad hoc basis, you can include it whenever necessary in your code instead.